# Releasing a previous Git tag with Maven

Tags: git, maven, maven-release-plugin

I created a Git tag for our application, 0.1.0, using the Maven release plugin, now we are preparing 0.2.0. We realized there is a bug in the 0.1.0 release so my coworker created a tag 0.1.1, manually (no Maven), including the fix.
I need to release the master branch of a that tag.
I did:

```
git checkout tags/0.1.1
mvn release:prepare
```

I get this error:

```
An error is occurred in the checkin process:
Exception while executing SCM command.
Detecting the current branch failed: fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref
```

How to fix it? By specifying the branch or something? (I didn't see that option in the Maven doc)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an error message from git saying `ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref` it means you've checked out a tag instead of a branch.

What you'll need to do is create a new branch from the tag (`git checkout -b fixing-0.1.1 0.1.1`) and then work on that instead.

(Under the covers, the `.git/HEAD` contains a 40-byte SHA hash instead of a `ref: refs/heads/master` which it would do if it were on a branch as a symbolic reference)

Comment: Let's say I want to release the master branch from that tag, what whould I have done?

Comment: What my answer told you to do.

Comment: When I do: git checkout tags/0.1.1, am I not in the master branch by default? Also In my case the fix has been committed in master.

Comment: No, you are in 'detached head' mode where you are pointing to exactly the commit that corresponds with tags/0.1.1. In SVN tags were branches so you could do this; in Git, a tag is simply a (fixed) pointer to an existing commit. In Git terminology, a branch is a pointer to a commit *that gets updated when you perform new commits*